# Javascript function returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I am working on an assignment where I have to print text into a textbox area with javascript. The user is allowed enter what they want as the 'objects' and 'destination' of the text. This method previous worked without the textbox but now that I added the textbox I have fun into countless errors. When looking in the console of chrome I keep getting an error saying "newVerse()" is undefined even though it's clearly defined as a function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      function newVerse()
      {

        var objects = document.getElementById('objectsID').value
        var destination = document.getElementById('destinationID').value

        var result = "Where have all the " + objects + " gone? <br /> + Long time passing. <br /> + Where have all the " + objects + " gone? <br /> + Long time ago. <br /> + Where have all the " + objects + " gone? <br /> + Gone to " + destination + ", everyone. <br /> + When will they ever learn? <br /> + When will they ever learn? <br />";

        result = document.getElementById('textboxid').value

      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<b>Objects Input</b>: <input TYPE="text" NAME="objects1" ID="objectsID" SIZE="20" />
<p>
<b>Destination Input</b>: <input TYPE="text" NAME="destination1" ID="destinationID" SIZE="20" />
<p>
<input TYPE="button" VALUE="Print Verse" onClick="newVerse()" />
<p>
<textarea id="textboxid" rows=10 cols=50>

</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you got `result = document.getElementById('textboxid').valu` backwards

Comment: "*I  keep getting an error saying "newVerse()" is undefined even though it's clearly defined as a function*" - yes, `newVerse` is defined as a function and calling it (`newVerse()`) does not `return` anything, and is therefore `undefined`.

Comment: looks like someone needs to learn the basics of JavaScript syntax

Comment: @Bergi: He's using an `onclick` attribute, so the return value isn't used anyway. I don't see any issue here.

Comment: Well, i switched 2 last lines of newVerse function and here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/51tkx8cu/

Comment: I too get that error in chrome when you don't have a doctype. Put `<!doctype html>` at the top of your document.

Comment: ...wait, now I'm not getting it. I had the error at first, but not any more. I think I hadn't run the JS code in JSBin before clicking the button. You should have a doctype anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <b>Objects Input</b>: <input type="text" name="objects1" id="objectsID" size="20" />
        <p>
        <b>Destination Input</b>: <input type="text" name="destination1" id="destinationID"       size="20" />
        <p>
        <input type="button" value="Print Verse" onclick="newVerse()" />
        <p>
        <textarea id="textboxid" rows=10 cols=50></textarea>
    </form>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function newVerse() {

        var objects = document.getElementById('objectsID').value;
        var destination = document.getElementById('destinationID').value;

        var result = "Where have all the " + objects + " gone? <br /> + Long time passing. <br />   + Where have all the " + objects + " gone? <br /> + Long time ago. <br /> + Where have all the " + objects + " gone? <br /> + Gone to " + destination + ", everyone. <br /> + When will they ever learn? <br /> + When will they ever learn? <br />";

        document.getElementById('textboxid').value = result;

    }
</script>
```

The only thing that is changed from your original code is where the textbox is populated with text:
Because you want to give an element (with a certain id) some content, well then you just type:

```
document.getElementById("idOfWhatEverElement").value = "This is the content";
```

And the last thing, as rule I made myself: If you don't put reference to the javascript code (as a separate file) in your html document, then don't type the javascript code in the head; put it at the end of the body (just as I have done now). That way you ensure the javascript have access to all DOM elements, because they are rendered before the script itself.

One last thing, try to follow xhtml standards, like always use closing tag where it is necessary:

```
<b>something bold</b> and <p>This is a paragraph</p>
```